# Adding color on a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add colors on an 2 dimensional array to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi79o.jpg

What I have created right now is this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzlQT.jpg

My code right now :

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Two-dimensional Arrays</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Two-Dimensional Arrays</h1>

<?php
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
        echo "<tr> \n";
        for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
           $p = $col * $row;
           echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        
        
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the part that you try to add the color?

Comment: Thank you for the question, I tried it with CSS and adding ids to the tr, td, however it doesn't work as I get an error. This is it: https://imgur.com/a/PaIAp48

Comment: Please __embed images__ to be viewed directly by simply putting an exclamation-mark before the image-link.

Comment: Noted for the next post, thanks you

Comment: I notted I can't embed images because I have <15 reputation as now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using CSS:

```
<style>
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

But if you want to do it in PHP, you can use inline styling:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<?php
    for ($row = 1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
        echo '<tr style="background-color: ' . ($row % 2 === 0 ? 'green' : 'red') . ';">';

        for ($col = 1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
           $p = $col * $row;

           echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }   
?>
</table>
```